# xcode fails to build C++ with Unknown type namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, swift3

- I have created a C++ project in Xcode 8.2.1 with a Bridging Header file.
- I have added a Point3.hpp and Point3.cpp file into a shared folder.
- The types for the cpp and cpp files (in the identity and type inspector) are Default - C++ Source and Default - C++ Header respectively.
- The LLVM 8.0 Language settings are:

  - C++11 [-std=c++11]
  - libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with with C++11 support)

When I try to build the project, I find that I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried searching to find information to resolve this issue, but most seem to be related to compiling source that is a combination of objective-C and C++ whereas this project was setup as a Swift3 project with C++ bridge. [Source code](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05846125509479575171)

*ex3-Bridging-Header.h*

`#import "../../../Shared/ex3/math/Point3.cpp"`

[image]

*Point3.cpp*

```
#include "Point3.hpp"
using namespace EX3;
Point3::Point3()
{
} ...
```

[image]

*Point3.hpp*

```
#ifndef EX3_POINT3_HPP
#define EX3_POINT3_HPP
namespace EX3
{
    class Point3
    {
    public:
        Point3(); ...
```

[image]

## compiler settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing looking, I finally managed to find a working solution. There may be other ways to achieve this but I fixed it by routing the C++ through an Objective C layer. Whilst this seems a little bit clumsy (as it adds an extra bridge layer), as of Swift3, it is reported that there is no direct interop layer to C++.

Comment: could you show how to do this? I have the same problem dealing with WebRTC